# How and when should I mount a remote filesystem using SSHFS?

Tags: linux, boot, startup, fstab, sshfs

I managed to get SSHFS working smoothly. I've added the following line to my /etc/fstab:

```
sshfs#xxx@remote_host:/path_to/remote/content /path_to/local/content fuse \
  comment=sshfs,noauto,user,exec,allow_other,reconnect,kernel_cache, \
  compression=no,cache_timeout=600,ServerAliveInterval=15 \
  0 0
```

I now can mount the remote filesystem by the following command:

```
mount /path_to/local/content
```

All is pretty and well but when should I issue the command above? I have a network application running on the box which needs the content from the remote box as soon as the application is started. I'd rather use *auto* instead of *noauto* but how can I be sure that the network is ready when the fstab is "executed"?

Comment: This sounds like a job for `autofs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu (10.10), the init daemons will try to mount again once the network has activated, so you should try to do as if it was working ok...

```
more /etc/init/mountall-net.conf 
# mountall-net - Mount network filesystems
#
# Send mountall the USR1 signal to inform it to try network filesystems
# again.
```

I guess most other linux flavours have the same kind of mechanism (to support SSHFS, NFS and all others network FS)...

hth !

Comment: This sound interesting! I do use Ubuntu 10.04. Though I'm not sure whether I understand what this means? Should I just use 'auto' and let the system do the rest?

Comment: Indeed ! I've not tried that by myself, but my EC2 instances which have network disk do work like a charm :) good luck !